# Css Dropdown menu fold open to the left

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I have a WordPress install with a custom menu.
This menu has two sub menu levels.

Like this:

```
+--------+-----------+--------+
| Menu 1 |  Menu 2   | Menu 3 |
+--------+-----------+--------+
|        |           | sub-1  |
|        |           | sub-2  |
|        | sub-sub-1 | sub-3  |
|        | sub-sub-2 |        |
|        | sub-sub-3 |        |
+--------+-----------+--------+
```

Normally the menu will fold open to the right. But I would like the last menu to fold to the left because of the fact that it will generate a horizontal scrollbar if it has a submenu.

Here is the code (PLEASE NOTE: I'm not seeking for somebody that changes the code for me to a solution) I just want the logic to do this because I want to understand what I'm doing.

http://pastebin.com/RTmy7SZT

M.

Comment: Ohw crap. LOL Hold on! -EDIT- I placed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `.last` class to Menu 3 using jQuery or use css selector `:last-child` to overwrite your css for the last menu item.

EG:

```
.menu-menu-container > ul > li.last > ul > li > ul.sub-menu{ right:100%; }
```

OR

```
.menu-menu-container > ul > li:last-child > ul > li > ul.sub-menu{ right:100%; }
```

Comment: Nice... I'll try this one. Thnx for the explanation

Comment: Thnx dude, This is what I used: `.menu-menu-container > ul > li:last-child > ul > li > ul.sub-menu{ left: -120%;}` The `right:100%` didn't overrule the `left:100%`. Even with `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use right instead of left.

```
.menu-menu-container > ul > li > ul > li > ul.sub-menu{
    right: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I only want it for the last top-level-menu-item